# Preventing errors when selecting element in destructured array

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-6

I'm fetching an object from an api with unreliable data. On this object, I need to select a specific item within an array.

Take this real selector as an example:

```js
const { text } = document.content[content.length - 1].content[0]
```

How do I prevent property undefined errors? Optional chaining won't return undefined on array selectors.

Would using try catch phrases be a valid approach?

```js
let lastChild;

try {
  lastChild = content[content.length - 1].content[0].text;
} catch {
  lastChild = false;
}
```

Comment: `try/catch` seems perfectly appropriate to me here.  You want to set a default value anyway so using optional chaining will still force you to check the result and set the default value - may as well just make the code show exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the `try/catch`.  That's my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Optional chaining won't return undefined on array selectors.

Optional chaining is in fact possible on array selectors:

```
// Will throw "Cannot read property 'test' of undefined"
undefined.test;
undefined['test'];

// Won't throw
undefined?.test;
undefined?.['test'];
```

In your example you can write

```
const text = content[content.length - 1]?.content?.[0]?.text;
console.log( text ); // Either a value or undefined
```

*As with all new language features, check whether the browser support is high enough for your project and consider transpiling otherwise.*

Answer (score 1):

There are ways you could implement this yourself, but personally I would just use the lodash `last` and `get` operator, which will allow you to pass in a path to what you're looking for, and a default value if it isn't found (in any part of the path)

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

[Lodash "last" operator](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#last)
e.g.

```
import { last, get } from 'lodash';

let lastElement = last(content); // gets the last element in an array
let lastChild = get(lastElement,'content[0].text', false); // gets the element at the string path in the second argument, with 3rd argument as the default / fallback value
```

In this case no try/catch is really needed because both methods handle undefined values gracefully. For example:

```
let returnsUndefined = last(undefined);

let handlesUndefinedValues = get(returnsUndefined, 'some.path', true)
console.log(handlesUndefinedValues) // logs "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would using try catch phrases be a valid approach?

Yes, `try/catch` seems perfectly appropriate to me here.  You want to set a default value anyway so using optional chaining will still force you to check the result and set the default value whereas `try/catch` already has the `catch` block built-in to make your code very obvious what it is doing in setting the default value.

IMO, you may as well just make the code more explicitly show exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the `try/catch` rather than use multiple cases of optional chaining and then check the result to set the default value if you ended up with `undefined`.  Sometimes the older tech just results in more obvious code.